# Installing AFNetworking pod for TVOs

Tags: ios, afnetworking, tvos

I am trying to install AFNetworking SDK through cocoapod to my TVOS project. I am constantly getting this error.

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `AFNetworking (= 3.0)` required by `Podfile`
```

My cocoapod version is `cocoapods-0.39.0` and here is Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :tvos, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'testing' do

pod 'AFNetworking' , '3.0'

end

target 'testingTests' do

end

target 'testingUITests' do

end
```

Can some body guide me how to get it working or is it not being supported currently according to this link https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2998

Comment: change the platform platform :tvos, '9.0' into platform :tvos, '8.0' and try once

Answer (score 4):

This shows a multi-platform Podfile that solves your AFNetworking issue.  In the end you have to specify a different version:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

inhibit_all_warnings!
xcodeproj 'MyAppSuite'

def common_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking', '3.0.0-beta.2'
    pod 'CocoaHTTPServer', :git => 'https://github.com/fkuehne/CocoaHTTPServer.git'
end


target :phoneApp do
    link_with 'YourIOSTargetNameHere'
    use_frameworks!
    platform :ios, '8.1'
    common_pods

end

target :tvApp do
    link_with 'YourTVOSTargetNameHere'
    use_frameworks!
    platform :tvos, '9.0'
    common_pods

end
```